# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole' but this ViewDataDictionary instance require

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I wanted to add a 'delete' method to my RolesController but I ran into this exception. "InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'SpaghettiOnline.Models.RoleEdit'".
Is there any way out how can I get the required view working??
Here's my code...

**RolesController.cs**

```
//Get : Admin/Roles/Delete/id=?
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    IdentityRole role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

    if (role == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(role);
}
```

**RoleEdit.cs**

```
public class RoleEdit
{
    public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AppUser> Members { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AppUser> NonMembers { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public string[] AddIds { get; set; }

    public string[] DeleteIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Delete.cshtml**

```
@model RoleEdit

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete Role";
}

<form asp-action="Delete" method="post">
    <div class="container p-3">
        <div class="border p-3">
            <h1 class="h2 mb-3">Delete Role</h1>
            <hr /><br />

            <input name="RoleName" value="@Model.Role.Name" hidden />
            <div>
                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-2">
                        Role Name
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-10">
                        @Model.Role.Name
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
            <button id="confirm-deletion" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:150px">Delete</button>
            <a asp-controller="Categories" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-light" style="width:150px">
                Back to List
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **Delete.cshtml** I just modified 3 lines of code and it worked for me...

```
@model Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole
```

instead of

```
@model RoleEdit
```

,

```
<input asp-for="Id" hidden />
```

instead of

```
<input name="RoleName" value="@Model.Role.Name" hidden />
```

and

```
<button id="confirm-deletion" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:150px" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Delete</button>
```

Just added `asp-route-id="@Model.Id"` to Delete button
and similarly changed the `@Model.Role.Name` to `@Model.Name`

Thanks for ur suggestion, Victor